# Strange error log results

Tags: php, mysql, logging, error-log

I keep getting errors popping up in my error log that look like this:

```
[12-Dec-2012 10:19:11] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: Access denied for user 'jcummings'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in ...<rest of the code here has been obfuscated>...
```

What I'm wondering about is the 'jcummings' (in this case) or whatever username shows up there.  I've had several different usernames show up, but it's never any username I have associated to my site, nor is it any variable in any database or anything on my site, really.  This happens only when I'm getting errors on a site, and it's giving me different names based on the site (sub-folder I'm testing different sites in) and different names at different times.

Is this something I should be concerned about, or is this just the php server throwing in a temp name?

EDIT:
My code looks something like this:

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
$var = stripslashes($var);
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var;

//connect
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("$dbName") or die ("Could not select DB");  

//query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $dbTable WHERE tarVar = '$var'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

So I'm not actually calling the action it until after the connection is made; the site is working fine like that right now, the error I copied was from earlier in the day.

Comment: I think you should be concerned, as it sounds like an attempt at a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Neither PHP nor MySQL randomly comes up with usernames to use. You're probably being attacked.

Comment: Have you dug through your web server logs to correlate requests near the same time that these appear? If not you need to do so, right now.

Comment: I wonder why attackers would call `mysql_real_escape_string()`...

Comment: That's the thing, they're only showing up when I'm generating errors with my own code, and the files that are generating these are so far buried in my webserver that there's no way anyone could know about them.

Comment: HUH? What the heck about this sounds like an **sql injection** attack? That makes absolutely no sense given the errors. There's nothing as of yet to indicate an attack... @MDWar: grep for those usernames in your applications. And are you using a different linux user for the webserver (suphp or the like)?

Comment: It looks like you're not the first https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=Access+denied+for+user+'jcummings'%40'localhost'#hl=en&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=LiC&tbo=d&channel=cs&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Access+denied+for+user+'jcummings'%40'localhost'+(using+password%3A+NO)%22&oq=%22Access+denied+for+user+'jcummings'%40'localhost'+(using+password:+NO)%22&fp=90c64075a4c88c14

Comment: And I should also add that it's showing up whether I'm working on my home desktop, work desktop, my laptop, and my moms laptop when I borrowed it.  All the SQL submissions are using the real_escape_string and stripslashes in order to prevent SQL injection, so is there any way where an un-identified username with no password is going to manage to inject anything here?

Comment: @ircmaxell I'd assume he already searched for jcummings when he said *"but it's never any username I have associated to my site, nor is it any variable in any database or anything on my site"*

Comment: And finally I should also add that these errors are only occurring on servers I'm currently working on, while I'm working on them (so if the error exists in the file, and I go to sleep, no new errors are created overnight).

Comment: @MDWar: Ok, time for more information. How did you install your server? What OS are you using? What host are you using? What version of PHP? What Extensions? Have you changed anything recently?

Comment: @ircmaxell, the sites are located on a webhosting service, I'm not terribly sure what type of server they're using

Comment: @MDWar: Have you filed a ticket with them? Contact their support, as they would likely be in a far better position to figure out this problem than we are...

Comment: Yeah, I'm calling them up right now to see what they say.  I would think normally since I'm trying to log in with my username it would show that, but the real_escape_string comes before my connection, so maybe it's the last user the PHP server processed?

Comment: Check this directive in your php.ini file http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-user if you don't have access to it then do this: echo ini_get('mysql.default_user'); just in case your host has a default user and somewhere in your code you did not specify user so it's using the default.

Comment: @MDWar: Well, you've figured out the root cause. You **need** to connect to the DB before calling `mysql_real_escape_string`. It won't work if you don't connect. Refactor your code (and follow up with the host)...

Comment: @MDWar: No, it's not working fine now. It looks like it is, but there are open vulnerabilities. There **must** be an active connection, and it **must** be the same one that you're querying against (if you have multiple open). So your code, while it appears that it's working, is **definitely** not.

Comment: I just spoke with the hosting company, they showed me where I can check every IP that's hit my site for the last 24 hours, and all 207 entries are from my computer I'm sitting in front of. I think @cryptic has the answer, some default user in the settings is being used in the place of root

Comment: Honestly this sounds like you're on a shared host with some bad configurations.

Comment: Surprised with all the comments it hasn't been stated, but please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Is your host Bluehost.com? or possibly HostMonster.com who is a reseller of Bluehost hosting?

Comment: I checked out @MikeB's Google link and looked up the hosting company that is being used by the sites that have the same error and they all use Bluehost, so it may appear that their database or setup has a default user.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure you are calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` before you have an open connection to a MySQL server. Although not required as a parameter, `mysql_real_escape_string()` needs a MySQL connection.

From the docs:

> **Optional parameter "link_identifier":**
> The MySQL connection. If the
>   link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by
>   mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to
>   create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no
>   connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is
>   generated.

Check for the files after the " in ..." in your log entry. Are these files part of your application? Are they modified? Or were they uploaded by an attacker?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is the correct answer to the original source of the error in the question...

Comment: My answer is the same as this one and was posted before it. Why the downvotes?

Comment: The real_escape wasn't the question, I was asking about the username that pops up.

Comment: @MDWar: I can't agree with you. The missing open connection is the actual source of the log entry and therefore the place to start investigations.

Comment: @MDWar: there are two types of answers to any question: 1. Those that solve the problem. And 2. Those that answer the literal question. The first type is infinitely more valuable...

Answer (score 1):

It means you need to connect to the MySQL database through `mysql_connect()` before you can use this function. Your credentials for `mysql_connect()` are probably incorrect.

Comment: As ZombieHunter said, The missing open connection is the actual source of the log entry and therefore the place to start investigations.